# Next q‌u‌e‌s‌t‌i‌o‌n android quiz

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How can I start a new question when I've already picked a choice? Sorry my code is kinda mess because I don't put it in some another Java file.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String MyPreferences = "MyPrefs";
    TextView lbl;
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);
    private TextView etQuestion;
    private TextView etAnswer1;
    private TextView etAnswer2;
    private TextView etAnswer3;
    private TextView etAnswer4;
    int score = 0;
    int qid =3;
    ListView lv;
    final Context context = this;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    private Context myContext;
    Question queryQ;
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.johnwhisker.schoolproject/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME ="school.db";
    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private String fileLink;
    public static final int requestcode = 1;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_make_test);
        etQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etQuestion);
        etAnswer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer1);
        etAnswer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer2);
        etAnswer3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer3);
        etAnswer4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etAnswer4);
        etAnswer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(etAnswer1.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        etAnswer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(etAnswer2.getText().toString());

            }
        });
        etAnswer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(etAnswer3.getText().toString());

            }
        });

        etAnswer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(etAnswer4.getText().toString());

            }
        });
        try {
            fileLink = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("1234", "d1: " + fileLink);
            File myDirs = new File(fileLink + "/databases");
            if (!myDirs.exists())
                myDirs.mkdirs();
            fileLink = fileLink + "/databases/" + DB_NAME;
            Log.d("1234", "d2: " + fileLink);
            File dbFile = new File(fileLink);
            if (!dbFile.exists()) {
                copydatabase();
            }
            Log.d("1234", "Question" + dbFile.exists());
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(fileLink, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
                getAllProducts();
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            lbl.setText("No activity can handle picking a file. Showing alternatives.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void cvChoice1OnSelect(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MakeTestActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
    }
    public void cvChoice2OnSelect(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddQuestionActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(i);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.left_to_right);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllProducts() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Question";
        Question quest = new Question();

        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTD(cursor.getString(5));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(6));
                quesList.add(quest);
                if(quest.getID()==1)
                {etQuestion.setText(quest.getQUESTION());
                    etAnswer1.setText(quest.getOPTA());
                    etAnswer2.setText(quest.getOPTB());
                    etAnswer3.setText(quest.getOPTC());
                    etAnswer4.setText(quest.getANSWER());
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return quesList;

    }
    public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
        ArrayList<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Question";
        Question quest = new Question();
        Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTD(cursor.getString(5));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(6));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (quest.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {
            score++;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"YOUR SCORE IS NOW" +score,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (quest.getID() < 3) {
            etQuestion.setText(quest.getQUESTION());
            etAnswer1.setText(quest.getOPTA());
            etAnswer2.setText(quest.getOPTB());
            etAnswer3.setText(quest.getOPTC());
            etAnswer4.setText(quest.getANSWER());
        }
    }
    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myinput = getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outfilename = fileLink;
        Log.d("1234", "e " + fileLink);
        File file = new File(outfilename);
        file.createNewFile();
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);
        Log.d("1234", "rer55");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (data == null)
            return;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case requestcode:
                String filepath = data.getData().getPath();
                controller = new DBController(getApplicationContext());
                SQLiteDatabase db = controller.getWritableDatabase();
                String tableName = "Question";
                db.execSQL("delete from " + tableName);
                try {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            FileReader file = new FileReader(filepath);
                            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
                            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                            String line = "";
                            db.beginTransaction();
                            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                                String[] str = line.split(",", 3);
                                Question quest = new Question();
                                contentValues.put("ID",quest.getID());
                                contentValues.put("QUESTION", quest.getQUESTION());
                                contentValues.put("A", quest.getOPTA());
                                contentValues.put("B", quest.getOPTB());
                                contentValues.put("C",quest.getOPTC());
                                contentValues.put("D",quest.getOPTD());
                                contentValues.put("ANSWER",quest.getANSWER());
                                db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);
                                lbl.setText("Successfully Updated Database.");
                            }
                            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                            db.endTransaction();
                            SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
                                    MyPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            prefs.edit().putBoolean("imported", true).commit();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            if (db.inTransaction())
                                db.endTransaction();
                            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                            d.setTitle(e.getMessage().toString() + "first");
                            d.show();
                            // db.endTransaction();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (db.inTransaction())
                            db.endTransaction();
                        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                        d.setTitle("Only CSV files allowed");
                        d.show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    if (db.inTransaction())
                        db.endTransaction();
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle(ex.getMessage().toString() + "second");
                    d.show();
                    // db.endTransaction();
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Question.java

```
public class Question {
    private int ID;
    private String QUESTION;
    private String OPTA;
    private String OPTB;
    private String OPTC;
    private String OPTD;
    private String ANSWER;
    public Question()
    {
        ID=0;
        QUESTION="";
        OPTA="";
        OPTB="";
        OPTC="";
        OPTD="";
        ANSWER="";
    }
    public Question(String qUESTION, String oPTA, String oPTB, String oPTC,String oPTD,
                    String aNSWER) {QUESTION = qUESTION;
        OPTA = oPTA;
        OPTB = oPTB;
        OPTC = oPTC;
        OPTD = oPTD;
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
    public int getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }
    public String getQUESTION() {
        return QUESTION;
    }
    public String getOPTA() {
        return OPTA;
    }
    public String getOPTB() {
        return OPTB;
    }
    public String getOPTC() {
        return OPTC;
    }
    public String getOPTD(){return OPTD;}
    public String getANSWER() {
        return ANSWER;
    }
    public void setID(int id)
    {
        ID=id;
    }
    public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
    }
    public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
        OPTA = oPTA;
    }
    public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
        OPTB = oPTB;
    }
    public void setOPTC(String oPTC) {
        OPTC = oPTC;
    }
    public void setOPTD(String oPTD)
    {
        OPTD = oPTD;
    }
    public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }

}'
```

Here is my code.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well actually I'm trying to start a new question whenever I press a TextView button with if statement is correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I worked on a project like this a while back...an alternative would be to use fragments...i wont post any code because your question is too vague
The idea is to have an activity with a fragment container...then a reusable fragment which is where your question will be displayed....so when you are initializing your fragment you pass in the question variables then your fragment displays it....when the user selects the next button,you store the answered question in an array and use fragment manager to switch the fragment with different parameters...the rest should be up to you

Comment: Yeah I think I will work with my code again. Anyway thank you

Comment: if you have any other issues just comment